# How to list all constraints of a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, constraints

How to list all constraints (Primary key, Foreign Key, check, unique mutual exclusive, ..) of a table in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Constraints of the table can be retrieved from [catalog-pg-constraint.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html) using the `SELECT` query.

```
SELECT con.*
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
        INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
        INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp ON nsp.oid = connamespace
        WHERE nsp.nspname = '{schema name}'
             AND rel.relname = '{table name}';
```

and the same can be viewed in `PSQL` using

```
\d+ {SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME}
```

Comment: Just a detail: If you don't have tables with the same name in multiple schemas, in PSQL just `\d+ {TABLE_NAME}` works too.

Answer (score 9):

> **Here is POSTGRES specific answer**
> **..... it will retrive all columns and their relationship as well**

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT
    pgc.contype as constraint_type,
    pgc.conname as constraint_name,
    ccu.table_schema AS table_schema,
    kcu.table_name as table_name,
    CASE WHEN (pgc.contype = 'f') THEN kcu.COLUMN_NAME ELSE ccu.COLUMN_NAME END as column_name, 
    CASE WHEN (pgc.contype = 'f') THEN ccu.TABLE_NAME ELSE (null) END as reference_table,
    CASE WHEN (pgc.contype = 'f') THEN ccu.COLUMN_NAME ELSE (null) END as reference_col,
    CASE WHEN (pgc.contype = 'p') THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END as auto_inc,
    CASE WHEN (pgc.contype = 'p') THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END as is_nullable,

        'integer' as data_type,
        '0' as numeric_scale,
        '32' as numeric_precision
FROM
    pg_constraint AS pgc
    JOIN pg_namespace nsp ON nsp.oid = pgc.connamespace
    JOIN pg_class cls ON pgc.conrelid = cls.oid
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu ON kcu.constraint_name = pgc.conname
    LEFT JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu ON pgc.conname = ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    AND nsp.nspname = ccu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
 
 UNION
 
    SELECT  null as constraint_type , null as constraint_name , 'public' as "table_schema" ,
    table_name , column_name, null as refrence_table , null as refrence_col , 'no' as auto_inc ,
    is_nullable , data_type, numeric_scale , numeric_precision
    FROM information_schema.columns cols 
    Where 1=1
    AND table_schema = 'public'
    and column_name not in(
        SELECT CASE WHEN (pgc.contype = 'f') THEN kcu.COLUMN_NAME ELSE kcu.COLUMN_NAME END 
        FROM
        pg_constraint AS pgc
        JOIN pg_namespace nsp ON nsp.oid = pgc.connamespace
        JOIN pg_class cls ON pgc.conrelid = cls.oid
        JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu ON kcu.constraint_name = pgc.conname
        LEFT JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu ON pgc.conname = ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        AND nsp.nspname = ccu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    )
)   as foo

ORDER BY table_name desc
```

Comment: Nice answer.  One bug on `auto_inc` : A `serial` type column should be `auto_inc` but doesn't have to be the primary key.     The current query will show column `id` with `auto_inc` as `false` for table  `CREATE TABLE public.test(id serial, ts int, tag text, metric1 int)`

Comment: Yea i have such scenario where i used pk then its auto inc always... thanks for correction.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not quite right. Given the SCCE:
`create table public.data (
 id integer constraint data_pk primary key
);
create schema other;
create table other.uses (
 id integer primary key
);
alter table other.uses add constraint uses_fk foreign key(id) references public.data;
`

It reports table _uses_ as being in the _public_ schema.

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't able to get the above solutions to work.  Maybe they're no longer supported or more likely I'm doing something wrong.  This is how I got it to work.  Note that the "contype" column will be abbreviated with the constraint type (e.g. 'c' for check, 'p' for primary key, etc.).  I include that variable in case you want to add a WHERE statement to filter for it after the FROM block.

```
select pgc.conname as constraint_name,
       ccu.table_schema as table_schema,
       ccu.table_name,
       ccu.column_name,
       contype,
        pg_get_constraintdef(pgc.oid)
from pg_constraint pgc
         join pg_namespace nsp on nsp.oid = pgc.connamespace
         join pg_class  cls on pgc.conrelid = cls.oid
         left join information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu
                   on pgc.conname = ccu.constraint_name
                       and nsp.nspname = ccu.constraint_schema
order by pgc.conname;
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple way of getting all constraints of a table in PostgreSQL

```
SELECT constraint_name, table_name, column_name, ordinal_position FROM information_schema.key_column_usage WHERE table_name = '<your_table_name>';
```

Comment: How do you also get it to show something is set to not null ? It shows my primary key but not the attributes that i declared not null for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This works for when you want to get **column name + constraint definition, filtered by schema + table**. A bit of a workaround, but works.

```sql
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(
        pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid) FROM 7
    ) as "check_definition",

    (REGEXP_MATCHES(
        SUBSTRING(pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid) FROM 7),
        'length\("([^"]+)"\)'
    ))[1] as "column_name"
    
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp ON nsp.oid = connamespace
WHERE
    nsp.nspname = 'my_schema'
    AND rel.relname = 'my_table'
    AND contype = 'c'; --only "check" constraints
```

```sql
| check_definition                                                                | column_name        |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------|
| (((length("User_Name") > 0) AND (length("User_Name") < 250)))                   | User_Name          |
| (((length("User_AccountNumber") > 0) AND (length("User_AccountNumber") < 250))) | User_AccountNumber |
| (((length("User_FirstName") > 0) AND (length("User_FirstName") < 250)))         | User_FirstName     |
| (((length("User_LastName") > 0) AND (length("User_LastName") < 250)))           | User_LastName      |
| (((length("User_PersonalEmail") > 0) AND (length("User_PersonalEmail") < 250))) | User_PersonalEmail |
| (((length("User_Phone") > 0) AND (length("User_Phone") < 250)))                 | User_Phone         |
| (((length("User_PlaceOfBirth") > 0) AND (length("User_PlaceOfBirth") < 250)))   | User_PlaceOfBirth  |
| (((length("User_WorkEmail") > 0) AND (length("User_WorkEmail") < 250)))         | User_WorkEmail     |
```

My regex assumes to be looking for the column name in a "text length constraint", the structure being like `(((length("User_Name") > 0) AND (length("User_Name") < 250)))`